# calling svg.selectAll(X).data().enter() multiple times

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a function drawticks that draws the ticks on an axis. Ticks come from a data structure that has their coordinates. Ticks [0] is ticks of the coarsest grain. ticks[4] or whatever the highest entry is has ticks of the finest grain. 
I'm trying to only draw ticks 0 for now.

```
function drawTicks(axis, width) {
  svg.selectAll("line")
    .data(data[axis].ticks[0])
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "pink")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("x1", function (d) {
      return xScale(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
      return h - yScale(d.y);
    })
    .attr("x2", function (d) {
      return xScale((d.x + (width * d.dx)));
    })
    .attr("y2", function (d) {
      return h - yScale((d.y + (width * d.dy)));
    });
}
```

I have called this from the console to test it separately on each axis. It behaves nondeterministically. Sometimes when I call it the second time it puts ticks on the 2nd axis and other times there is no response.

I want to have a for loop that iterates through all of the axes rather than calling them one by one, but this doesn't work for the same reason that it doesn't work in the console.

I know that I could instead say svg.append(line) for each tick mark rather than using data().enter(), but I feel like d3 conventions would want me to use data instead of iterating through the points in my data structure.

Comment: You're applying all the attributes to the `enter()` selection, which, on subsequent calls, doesn't update the ticks that have already been created and styled in previous calls. You need to assign the selection to a var, like `var ticks = svg.selectAll("line").data(data[axis].ticks[0])`, then `ticks.enter().append('line')` (can also set stroke and fill here). Then apply the rest of the attributes to `ticks` (without `enter()`).

Comment: I'll try this, but I still don't really understand the answer. 

if we distribute the code into three statements, 
var ticks = etc...
ticks.enter() and 
ticks.attr(etc etc etc), 
I don't see how that's different semantically than the original except for being split up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. In order to not override other lines, here is my final code:

```
function drawTicks(level, axis, wid){

var myClass = "axis"+axis+"-level"+level;
    svg.selectAll("."+"myClass")
        .data(data[axis].ticks[level])
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("stroke", "pink")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("class", myClass)
                }
```